# SPSiteDataQuery fails if field of type UserMulti is specified in ViewFields

Tags: sharepoint

I`m trying to query all task lists. **I have modified** default Task content type **to allow multiple choices** for Assigned To field (Internal name - AssignedTo).

My SPSiteDataQuery fails if I specify `<FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' />` (Returns no results)
If I add `Nullable='TRUE'` then results are returned but AssignedTo field ends up being null for all records. If i'll add `Type='UserMulti'`, that won't help.

Looks like a very nasty bug. Is there a workaround? (Well, besides looping all task lists and querying...)

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We faced the same exact issue two months back, I came across [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/bc7e2e97-c29f-4fcd-a74a-cf6238a1836a) , after which I used the `Nullable='TRUE' Type='UserMulti'` Still then we were not able get it working. And my manager sat with MS support to just find out that Installing the MOSS 2007 SP2 solved the issue with out a code change. You can try out SP2 in case if you haven't already.

Comment: Ah, i`v already got SP2. Even the latest cumulative updates for WSS.

Comment: Maybe there is some problem with cumulative update, because it WAS working before (when i had SP2). Maybe after awhile it will be ok again.